# Dummy Output Sound Error

Tags: sound, 19.10

So, suddenly my system has no sound, on Settings -> Audio there's only one option: Dummy Output.

I tried alsamixer but it gives an error:

`cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`

There's no alsa-base.conf file in /etc/modeprobe.d.

Pavucontrol doesn't recognize any cards.

If I run pulseaudio it gives

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Any suggestions? This is my first post, so sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: My Ubuntu machine does that too sometimes. Usually, when I reboot the machine, the problem is fixed. Do try it and see if your problem was fixed.

Comment: Actually, just rebooted and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I've tried the kernel 5.3.28 in Grub (Advanced options to Ubuntu) and the sound works. The problem is in kernel 5.3.42.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that Ubuntu fixed this, I've tried kernel 5.4 and 5.5 and doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. After logging in when using kernel 5.3.28 or 5.3.40 the computer freezes.